# change button color Lightbox

Tags: css

I'm using classic Galleria theme. I implemented the lightbox and changed the frame color:

```
.galleria-lightbox-shadow{background-color: transparent !important}
.galleria-lightbox-content{background:black !important}
```

But is it possible to change the color of the next, previous and close buttons in Lightbox?

Right now they are white. I would like to have them in black. Is there a solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

If my hunch is correct, the '**next**', '**previous**' and '**close**' buttons are **images** (as is with most Lightboxes).

You should edit the images in their folder and convert them into black-themed ones manually, or search online for any replacements.

Comment: I would manually change them if I know where they are located. I simply added
Galleria.configure({ lightbox: true});  line to my Html script and I got this default Lightbox added to my Galleria. I'm not an expert here...could you tell me where I can locate those images?

Comment: um, its in your html folder, probably. such as yourhost/images

Comment: I found that it was not actual images, but rather styled text. For some reason styling for next and prev did not worked for me until I implemented actual div code in my html... Anyway it's working now. Thank you for responding  Reno Yeo.